# How to Link A certain Keyboard Key to a function in React JS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, event-handling, web-development-server

I have made an App that is simple you can check it out [here](http://todo-list-by-prasoon.herokuapp.com) but the problem is now that when a user is logged in and creating a post there is a button that adds a post now I want "Enter" key to perform the same task the code to my button is

```
<Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick = {updateList}>Add item</Button>
```

now I want to bind the same `updateList` function to Enter key please guide me on how can I do that???

The button is from Material-ui

also currently as I click enter key it reloads the page I also want to stop that from happening

Also, can anyone tell me that is it possible to take multikey stroke input like `ctrl + Z` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bind function to some key you can do it by event listeners called onKeyDown or onKeyPress:

```html
handleKeyPress = (event) => {
  if(event.key === 'Enter'){
    console.log('enter press here! ')
  }
}
function App(){
     return(
         <div>
           <input type="text" id="one" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
        </div>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you pager is reloading im guessing your using the HTML form tag. To prevent it the page from reloading your need to prevent the default event behavior after submitting.

```
<form onSubmit={(event) => {event.preventDefault() /* this stops reloading the page */ }} ></form>
```

To be able to submit on enter, you should add a button in side the form tag and add type "submit" to it.

```
<form onSubmit={(event) => {event.preventDefault() /* this stops reloading the page */ }} >
  <button type={"submit"}/>
</form>
```

That should do it.